# Defining an alias and immediately use it

Tags: zsh, alias

In `zsh` this works fine:

```
alias foo=ls
foo
```

But this does not:

```
alias foo=ls; foo
```

Pressing enter an extra time is not an issue when running interactively. But when running through `ssh` it suddenly becomes a problem:

```
% ssh zsh@server 'alias foo=ls; foo'
zsh:1: command not found: foo
```

Even with a newline it does not work:

```
% ssh zsh@server 'alias foo=ls;
foo'
zsh:2: command not found: foo
```

The weird thing is that `zsh` knows it is aliased:

```
% ssh zsh@server 'alias foo=ls; alias'
foo=ls
run-help=man
which-command=whence
```

How do tell `zsh` that the aliases should be active?

Comment: It's a common problem with aliasing. I tried it using `bash` and `csh` and they behaved the same way. I hope someone could explain that.

Comment: Bash is not a problem: ssh server 'shopt -s expand_aliases;alias jj=ls\njj'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can not do it.

Because aliases were expanded only after history expansion and entire line was read in one go, so when `foo` was executed, the alias expansion process was gone, it's too late for the shell to recognize new alias.

The best way you can do is defining alias in `.zshrc` or using function like [jimmij's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/223537/38906) or using `eval`:

```
alias foo=ls; eval foo
```

---

There's a [special case with zsh -c](http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2014/msg01600.html). In this case, those aliases which were defined in `.zshenv` will be expanded.

Comment: That wouldn't explain why `ssh host 'alias foo=bar<newline>foo'` doesn't work. [There's a special case for `zsh -c`](http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2014/msg01600.html)

Comment: Or use `alias foo=ls; eval foo`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Thanks for the information, updated with them. About `ssh` case, could you please make it more clear. I think the command was still read in one go.

Answer (score 11):

This is very well known problem which is even described in `zsh` manual under chapter ALIASING (see `man zshmisc`). The recomended way of dealing with it is to use function instead of alias:

```
foo() { ls; } ; foo
```

or even better in case of `ls`:

```
foo() { ls -- "${@:-.}"; } ; foo
```

---

<sub>ps. semicolon at the end of the function definition (list) and spaces are not needed in zsh, but as a habit from other shells I still put them.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Using the c-shell (tcsh to be exact) from the command line:

```
mymachine % alias showme "echo here it is"
mymachine % showme
here it is
```

or put it in the .cshrc file then source the file:

```
mymachine % source ~/.cshrc

mymachine % showme
here it is

mymachine % ssh garnet showme
here it is
```